# Pipe commands in bash function

Tags: bash, function

When you define a bash function you can call bash commands with `command` command.

```
function ls() {
  clear
  command ls "$@"
}
```

How would you pipe commands in bash function?

e.g.

```
function ls() {
  clear
  command ls "$@" | head
}
```

EDIT: The output would be OK, but there is `--color=auto`. Look [here](http://pastebin.com/XcGtgVW7)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: ls function will be `clear; ls | head` , but I want function, not alias

Comment: Are you trying to override the builtin `ls`?

Comment: What's the problem with your function? Works for me.

Comment: I would just name the alias another way. What if a script depended on how ls works?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [Here](http://pastebin.com/XcGtgVW7) are my functions. `lsh` don't give colored output.

Comment: If I use `--color=auto` it doesn't give me color either, but if I remove `=auto` I get colors. It's because `auto` makes `ls` output in color only when printing to a terminal, not a pipe.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I thought this detail is not important. I will edit the question.

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to pipe the colours through `head`. Additionally there isn't any built in "return n lines" option in `ls`, that's sort of what piping is all about.

Comment: @LewisNorton Why this can't be done? I must satisfy without colors?

Comment: OK, I think I understand it. ls does not output information about color. I will accept Lewis's solution. Please add this info to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your `~/.bashrc`

```
function ls() { clear ; builtin ls "$@" | head ; }
```

It's similar to the function you have already but with the inclusion of `builtin`, it guarantees not to get stuck in a loop calling itself. Hope this works!

EDIT: It should be noted that any colour information produced by `ls` with the `--color=auto` option won't be carried through the pipe to head.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the colour information generated by the `ls` command to `head` if you run `ls` in a so-called pseudo terminal (so that `ls` thinks it is writing its output to a terminal, and not a pipe). This can be achieved by using the `script` command.

```
ls() {
   type -P command 1>/dev/null || 
        { echo 'No "command" executable found!'; return 1; }
   clear
   script -q /dev/null command ls -G "$@" | tr -d '\r' | head
 }


 cat /usr/bin/command   # on Mac OS X 10.6.8
 #!/bin/sh
 # $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $
 # This file is in the public domain.
 builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

For more information see: [ls command operating differently depending on recipient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/ls-command-operating-differently-depending-on-recipient)